# How do I add a row of data referencing interactive variables when a button is clicked using Python plotly-dash

Tags: python, jupyter, plotly-dash

I have a number of interactive input and output data in a Dash app. I have created a button where it if clicked it should create and then subsequently add (with later clicks) a row of data to a table.

This is a simplified version of my code:

```
app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.CERULEAN])

app.layout = html.Div([
    dbc.Row(dbc.InputGroup([dbc.InputGroupText("Top"), dbc.Input(id='T',placeholder="Project Name")],className="mb-3")),
    dbc.Row(dbc.InputGroup([dbc.InputGroupText("Base"), dbc.Input(id='B',placeholder="Project Name")],className="mb-3")),
    
    dbc.Row([
        html.Div([
            dbc.Button("Add current data to sensitivity table", id='add-row', style={'font-family':'arial','marginTop':'5px','marginRight':'10px'}, className="d-grid gap-2 col-8", size="sm"),
        ])
    ]),
        
    dbc.Row([
        dt.DataTable(id='sensitivity',columns=[{'name': col, 'id': col} for col in ['TR', 'BR']], data=[]),
        dcc.Store(id='button-clicks', data=0)
    ]),
])

@app.callback(
    Output('button-clicks', 'data'),
    Input('add-row', 'n_clicks'),
)

def update_button_clicks(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks is None:
        return 0
    return n_clicks

@app.callback(
    Output('sensitivity','data'),
    Input('button-clicks', 'data'),
    State(component_id='T', component_property='value'),
    State(component_id='B', component_property='value'),
)

def sensitivityTable(n_clicks,T,B):
    if n_clicks == 0:
        return dash.no_update

    new_row_data = {
        'Top':T, 
        'Base':B
    }

    if current_data is None:
        current_data = []
    current_data = dash.callback_context.outputs_list[0]['data']
        
    sensitivity_updated_data = current_data + [new_row_data]

    return sensitivity_updated_data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(port=8054,debug=True)
```

The expected outcome is that when the button is clicked, a row of data is added taken from the current input value.

However I get an attribute error: 'str' object has no attribute 'value'

I've been playing around trying to solve this but no luck so far - is anyone able to see where I am going wrong. If there is a better way to interactively add data referencing a set of variables then that would also be great also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following changes:

```py
import pandas as pd

import dash
from dash import dcc, html
from dash import Input, Output, State, callback
from dash import dash_table as dt

import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

app = dash.Dash(external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.CERULEAN])

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dbc.Row(
            dbc.InputGroup(
                [
                    dbc.InputGroupText("Top"),
                    dbc.Input(id="T", placeholder="Project Name"),
                ],
                className="mb-3",
            )
        ),
        dbc.Row(
            dbc.InputGroup(
                [
                    dbc.InputGroupText("Base"),
                    dbc.Input(id="B", placeholder="Project Name"),
                ],
                className="mb-3",
            )
        ),
        dbc.Row(
            [
                html.Div(
                    [
                        dbc.Button(
                            "Add current data to sensitivity table",
                            id="add-row",
                            style={
                                "font-family": "arial",
                                "marginTop": "5px",
                                "marginRight": "10px",
                            },
                            className="d-grid gap-2 col-8",
                            size="sm",
                        ),
                    ]
                )
            ]
        ),
        dbc.Row(
            [
                dt.DataTable(
                    id="sensitivity",
                    columns=[
                        {"name": col, "id": col} for col in ["TR", "BR"]
                    ],
                    data=[],
                ),
                dcc.Store(id="button-clicks", data=0),
            ]
        ),
    ], style={"margin": "20%"}
)


@app.callback(
    Output("button-clicks", "data"), Input("add-row", "n_clicks"),
)
def update_button_clicks(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks is None:
        return 0
    return n_clicks


@app.callback(
    Output("sensitivity", "data"),
    Input("button-clicks", "data"),
    State("sensitivity", "data"),
    State(component_id="T", component_property="value"),
    State(component_id="B", component_property="value"),
)
def sensitivityTable(n_clicks, current_data, T, B):
    if n_clicks == 0:
        return dash.no_update

    # Adjusted the keys to match column IDs
    new_row_data = {"TR": T, "BR": B}

    if current_data is None:
        current_data = []

    sensitivity_updated_data = current_data + [new_row_data]

    return sensitivity_updated_data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(port=8054, debug=True)
```

result in this app behavior:
[image: Video screen shot recording of dash app]

The issues with your code I had to change were:

1. `current_data` (the current state of the data in the data table) can be input using `State` rather than `dash.ctx` (which was the source of the error you cite)
2. You need to use the columns of the data table as the keys for adding new rows to the table - the input `T` & `B` will be the new data in each added row